# Sorting alphabetically using a Proc

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to sort some names alphabetically by passing a custom comparator to sort but i can't seem to get it to work.

**controller**

```
def show
  @media_deals = resource.media_deals
  @media_deals.sort!(&sort) if params[:sort].present?
end

def sort
  resource_class::SORTING[params[:sort]]
end
```

**model**

```
SORTING = {
  cost_ascending: Proc.new {|a, b| a.monthly_cost <=> b.monthly_cost },
  cost_descending: Proc.new {|a, b| b.monthly_cost <=> a.monthly_cost },
  supplier_a_to_z: Proc.new {|a, b| a.name.casecmp(b.name) },
  supplier_z_to_a: Proc.new {|a, b| b.name.casecmp(a.name) },
}.with_indifferent_access
```

The cost sorting works fine but when it comes to sorting alphabetically nothing happens. Can anyone suggest what to do here?

Comment: Add `pry` gem as development dependency, modify sorter to `supplier_a_to_z: Proc.new {|a, b| require 'pry'; binding.pry; a.name.casecmp(b.name) }`, force the desired sorter to be invoked and examine `a.name` and `b.name`.

Comment: thanks @mudasobwa turns out the names were the same! oops, sorry all

Comment: I'll vote this as "cannot reproduce," then, since there's no problem here for us to solve.  I'm glad you got it figured out.